# Get iframe element of current CKEDITOR instance

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

CKEditor 4 or above
I have a CKEDITOR instance that I can access without problem `parent.CKEDITOR.instances[instance_id]`
I want to add bootstrap file to the head of the iframe generated by CKEDITOR (kind of hack, because normal way to add optional css file was not working).
I tried to get the iframe head and to inject the bootstrap file, but it fails always.
Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally, I post it here so maybe it will be helpful for someone in the future.
I just added the bootstrap file to the body tag (it is a bad practice but it works).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classic editor with contents in iframe then please use [contentsCss configuration setting](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) to add extra CSS to editor contents area. It is important to refresh the cache with Ctrl+F5. If for some reason changes are not applied and path to CSS file is correct (you are not getting 404 in browser dev-tools console) then you might want to try clearing cache according to this [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache).

If you really need to get to the iframe, you can use below technique. It gets you the div with `editor id` you need and it finds `iframe` for it. This is good if you have couple of editors or iframes on a single page.

```
document.getElementById('cke_'+ your_textarea_id ).getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow
```